# I am having trouble with a python syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I need help as I was watching a video on how the cicada3301 puzzles were solved. One of them, I forgot which one, said that python could be used to find the two prime number which, when multiplied, will give the number. I tried copying down the code myself and testing it in python but I am confused on how I am supposed to run it and why I got that syntax error.

Here is what the code looked like:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> def goldbach_conj(number):
    x, y = '74674927695793569672701974404037902831935259177874331197231759008957255433116469469882489015469125000179524189783 result = 0 15469125000179524189783',
    if not number % 2:
        prime_list=list_of_primes(number)
        while result != number:
            for i in range(len(prime_list)):
                x = prime_list[i]
                if result == number:
                    break
                for j in range(len(prime_list)):
                    y = prime_list[j]
                    result = x + y
                    print("Adding {} and {}.".format(x, y))
                    print("Result is {}".format(result))
                    if result == number:
                        break
                    return x, y
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `x,y = ...` what do you think this line is doing?

Comment: I do not know why but it says that the six in the python 3.6.0 is a syntax error

Comment: Can u try to explain, what does that x, y do??? or else try pasting the source from where you got the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here, It should  `x,y='value1','value2'`

You have only given `x,y='value1',`, what is `y`?